# Can't access value from controller (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to access values from my query in view.

```
$bookings = DB::table('bookings')
            ->join('staffs', 'staffs.id' , '=', 'bookings.staff_id')
            ->join('customers', 'customers.id' , '=', 'bookings.customer_id')
            ->select('bookings.id', 'bookings.start_time',  'bookings.end_time', 'bookings.service', 'staffs.name as Staff-Name',  'customers.name as Customer-Name')
            ->orderBy('customers.name', 'desc')
            ->get();

        return view('booking.index')->with('bookings', $bookings);
```

This is simple enough to understand. What I am trying to do is that i want to get start_time, end_time which are in bookings table, name which is staffs table also name in customers table.

Right now I am doing like:

```
@foreach($bookings as $booking)
  {{ $booking->start_time }}
  {{ $booking->end_time }} 
  {{ $booking->name }} // name column which is in customers table
@endforeach
```

But these things don't seem to work.

Comment: Print the value of  $bookings like  dd($bookings)

Comment: I am getting expected result when i am doing dd($bookings), but now when {{ $booking->start_time}}

Answer (score 2):

It's all because you are using column names instead of **aliases** which you set.

Take a look at it, by example customers.name is named **Customer-Name**.

```
->select('bookings.id', 'bookings.start_time',  'bookings.end_time', 'bookings.service', 'staffs.name as Staff-Name',  'customers.name as Customer-Name')
```

If you want to access data you need to do it like that:

```
@foreach($bookings as $booking)
  {{ $booking->start_time }}
  {{ $booking->end_time }} 
  {{ $booking->Customer-Name }} // name of alias
@endforeach
```

Anyway I don't think that dash in alias is good solution, you should use underscore instead. `(customers.name as Customer_Name)` and `$booking->Customer_Name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$bookings = DB::table('bookings')
        ->join('staffs', 'staffs.id' , '=', 'bookings.staff_id')
        ->join('customers', 'customers.id' , '=', 'bookings.customer_id')
        ->select('bookings.id', 'bookings.start_time',  'bookings.end_time', 'bookings.service', 'staffs.name as Staff-Name',  'customers.name as Customer-Name')
        ->orderBy('customers.name', 'desc')
        ->get();

        return view('booking.index')->with(compact('bookings'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The $bookings contains an array of data. You can print these in your view ike this..

```
@foreach($bookings as $booking)
    {{$booking->start}}
    {{$booking->end_time}}
@endforeach
```